# Failing to click on print (image element) on a webpage using selenium (python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I am trying to click on the print option on this webpage:

(http://agence-prd.ansm.sante.fr/php/ecodex/frames.php?specid=65123812&typedoc=R&ref=R0306505.htm)

I am using the code below:

```
link ='http://agence-prd.ansm.sante.fr/php/ecodex/images/icoimp.gif'
image_elements = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@align='center']/a/img[@src='"+link+"']")
image_element.click()
```

I have tried many different options to find the element but I get error :

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@align='center']/a/img[@src='http://agence-prd.ansm.sante.fr/php/ecodex/images/icoimp.gif']"}

I think I am missing out on something. It'll be great if someone can help me here. 
[image: html in image]
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This element is present  within a iframe please refer below solution to solve your issue:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"../driver/chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("http://agence-prd.ansm.sante.fr/php/ecodex/frames.php?specid=65123812&typedoc=R&ref=R0306505.htm")

iframe=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME,"left")))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
printButton=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//body[@class='menu']//div//a//img")))
printButton.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
image_elements = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/a/img")
image_element.click()
```